# Flex 3: application complete question

Tags: apache-flex, function

my main mxml piece loads 3 children.  Each one of these 3 children then loads 12 children of their own.  My question is, is there a way I can have a function run once all the children, and grandchildren are fully done loading?  I've tried using creationComplete as well as applicationComplete, and the function is still running after the main mxml is loaded...

Comment: I can't think of an easy answer in Flex 3... all my thoughts are coming up with some manual process of using callLater and creationPolicy set to "all". If you ever do get your project to Flex 4+, there's now a contentCreationComplete event. Maybe you can look at that code in the Flex 4+ framework and see how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this [Flex 3 Livedoc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_3.html)? It's quite difficult without the MXML to figure out what you mean exactly. As @Jonathan mentions above, looking at creationPolicy in the above link should try explain some of the creation and initialization steps you need to understand.